# Degree of freedom input for Monte Carlo simulation of asset returns with multivariate t distribution

Tags: portfolio-optimization, monte-carlo, simulations, distribution, multivariate

How do I calculate or estimate the degrees of freedom in order to perform a Monte Carlo simulation of asset returns with multivariate t distribution using R functions? I am able to calculate the mean vector of asset returns `mu`, as well as the covariance matrix `covmat` of asset returns.
I also understand that `Sigma` is the scale matrix which is `covmat * df/(df-2)`

```
library(mvtnorm)
sim <- rep(mu, each = n) + rmvt(n, sigma=Sigma, df=df)
#df is degrees of freedom, which is a required input in the function rmvt and
required to calculate the scale matrix
```

Comment: Couple of pointers here (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63647/estimating-parameters-of-students-t-distribution) and the references therein!

Comment: What degrees of freedom is typically used for financial returns?